# Top menu works with tabs. Submenu doesn't work with tabs

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, tabs

menu: **LUCAS base_url('lucas')**. submenu: **deel_1 (base_url('lucas/view/1')**. In controller two functions (index($choice="all) and view($choice) are going to the same view folder/page. In this page I load the particular part(**lucas_tabrow_1, 2 or lucas_tabrow_all**) Only the last one works! The tqo not working are coming from the submenu! Hovering over a tabrow part shows in the status: localhost/lucas/view/1#. The correct one shows: localhost/lucas#

I tried to make a tabrow with 10 menus / dropdown menus. This is too big so I try to make 2 tabrows and only load one at the time. Clicking on topmenu Lucas goes correct, but trough submenu it doesnn't work

Comment: can you share your code? screenshot of what is expected... a MVCE is needed here

Comment: I ' am working on the code and some screenshots. I will get back to You.